# To create xml file inside the direct of the project of my mobile XAMARIN

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

I want to create an xml file inside the directory of my project, so also create a command where I can edit and subscribe it. How can I increment this in my project in a simple and basic way?

```
XDocument rss = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(url);
rss.Save(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/inicio.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
var filename = Path.Combine(path, "inicio.xml");
rss.Save(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(assets.Open(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + @"/rss.xml")))
        {
            xmlString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

This way of error